# select multiple column into a single row

Tags: sql

Suppose I've got two tables:

Table A:

```
Item1Name  Item1Code  Item2Name   Item2Code
ABC         001         DEF          002
```

Table B:

```
ItemCode     ItemType
  001        Cookware
  002         Drinks
```

What should the select statement be to generate following result?

```
Item1Name  Item1Code  Item2Name   Item2Code   Item1Type    Item2Type
ABC         001         DEF          002       Cookware      Drinks
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Add a few more rows of sample data, and adjust the expected result accordingly.

Comment: You are looking for a join. Google might be helpful: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Yeah. But I have no idea what would it be.

Comment: try `inner join` both tables, it would be worth of you making an attempt

Comment: It is generally expected that you show "some research effort" (cf. "Search, and research" on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This is also an upvote criteria, you will get better results on this page.

Comment: How many columns in Table A? Do you have a set number of "Items"? If not then you have a bad table design. What happens when Item3Code becomes available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you have an item detail table (Table B) that holds the item characteristics and another table that relates 2 items (Table A). You should start with Table A and join twice with Table B (once for each item), to get their characteristics.

```
SELECT
    A.Item1Name,
    A.Item1Code,
    B1.ItemType,
    A.Item2Name,
    A.Item2Code,
    B2.ItemType
FROM
    TableA A
    LEFT JOIN TableB B1 ON A.Item1Code = B1.ItemCode
    LEFT JOIN TableB B2 ON A.Item2Code = B2.ItemCode
```

You should check if you need an `INNER` or `LEFT` join (left will return `NULL` if no matching record is found).

Comment: Have you searched for duplicates on this site?